# Evolis Primacy Linux Compatibility

Tags: software-recommendation, hardware

Does anyone have any experience of using the Evolis Primacy ID Card Printer with Ubuntu? If so, how easy is it to use/configure.

Can anyone recommend any good software for designing the cards?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Basically : it's a complete pain.

- Drivers are copies from `macOS-cups`, so you have to **modify** the `ppd.gz`,

  (cups says `filter missing` and the the **problem is** that the **ppd refers** to some **files in the wrong location** under `/Library/...`)
- **Status** can **only** be **monitored** with the **Windows "Print Center"** ( until somebody deciphers their protocol )
- **Duplex** key **has to be activated in Windows "Print Center"**, and you have to send 2 pages (1 Front , 2 Back)

### Labels:

For the labels you might try **glabels**.

I personally use GIMP with the "digital print template" from [here on youcard.de](https://www.youcard.de/download/druckvorlagen-fuer-plastikkarten/), because you have to send the proper "paper size" (card).

(For double side printing you could just

- "merge visible layers" in GIMP
- then duplicate the 1 remaining layer
- export the file as MNG (e.g. `test.mng`)
- then `convert file.mng file.pdf`

to yield a multi page pdf.)

---

### Printing Modes:

Example for MonochromeMultiplex :

```
lpadmin -pEVOLIS-Primacy -o GDuplexMode=DUPLEX_MM -o GRibbonType=RM_KBLACK ;lpr  -o landscape -o fit-to-page -o media=Card -PEVOLIS-Primacy Vorlage-Digital-Plastikkartendruck.pdf
```

possible printing modes: `'SIMPLEX','DUPLEX_CC','DUPLEX_CM','DUPLEX_MM','DUPLEX_MC'`

---

### Ribbon Selection:

it is important to select the according ribbon mode

this is one of

- 'RC_YMCKO'
- 'RC_YMCKOS'
- 'RC_YMCKOK'
- 'RC_YMCKOKOS'
- 'RM_KO'
- 'RM_KBLACK'
- 'RM_KWHITE'
- 'RM_KRED'
- 'RM_KGREEN'
- 'RM_KBLUE'
- 'RM_KSCRATCH'
- 'RM_KMETALSILVER'
- 'RM_KMETALGOLD'
- 'RM_KSIGNATURE'
- 'RM_KWAX'
- 'RM_KPREMIUM'
- 'RM_HOLO'`

---